# laptop curl Youtube API v3 request always returns 'Exceeded Quota' error

Tags: youtube-data-api

Every time I attempt to use the following simple bash script command on my Macbook Pro laptop, I get an 'Exceeded Quota' error.  I do supply a valid API key and I'm under the impression that I don't need any other tokens because I am only requesting Public information (a simple list of songs).

Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl \
  'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=music&type=video&key=[My API key]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

Reply:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your \u003ca href=\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\"\u003equota\u003c/a\u003e.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your \u003ca href=\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\"\u003equota\u003c/a\u003e.",
        "domain": "youtube.quota",
        "reason": "quotaExceeded"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I don't have any quota problems pulling song lists via the YouTube Data API 'list' page:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Comment: What do you mean by (quote): *I don't have any problems pulling song lists via the YouTube Data API 'list' page*? What is in fact this thing *YouTube Data API 'list' page*?

Comment: This is the API link.  You can fill in the values, send the request and you will receive a JSON reply:   https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Comment: That's the `Search.list` API endpoint's official doc page.

Comment: Did you used the same API key on your `curl` call and on the `Search.list`'s doc page?

Comment: I created a new api key on my dashboard to use in the curl request.  I don't know how to verify the exact api key being used by the Search.list doc page.  When I click on the Show Code button, the api key is obscured.   BTW..thanks for helping me!

Comment: I'm using the Try It! feature via the Search.list API endpoint doc page.  I don't know how to find what API key it is using.  I assumed it was using the API key I created on my dashboard.

Comment: No. The *Try It!* feature is using by default a separate API key, not your own API key obtained from Google's developers console. The `Search.list` web page has no means of knowing your API key; that's your private credentials data.

Comment: Ok..that makes sense.  I just need to know what I'm missing when I try to send the curl command from my laptop.  Do I need to call a different API to create a new key in the bash script prior to sending the curl command.  I'm really confused, but again, thanks for helping me!

Comment: Basically, there are two possibilities for *your API key* to generate the `quotaExceeded` error on the `Search.list` API endpoint: (1) indeed you've exceeded your daily quota (that's normally 10000 units; each `Search.list` call costs 100 units; thus 100 calls to this endpoint, not accounting others, and you're out of quota); (2) your project has been disabled by Google for some reason (for example: 90 days of inactivity or non-compliance with the terms of service).

Comment: @stvar, I got it to work by creating a new project and then creating an API key within the new project.  Is there a way to 're-activate' a project?  Even though I use the API frequently, the way I've been using it apparently allowed the old project to exceed the 90 day inactivity limit.  THANKS A MILLION!!!!

Comment: Yes, there's is: fill up [this form](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form?hl=en) and, upon the auditing process, you'll get back your original quota (or more, if you ask it). Be aware of the fact that auditing can take quite some time, according to the experience of users of this forum.